# How to capture plain text site into a variable using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to save all the content of a website inside a variable in order to search for a specific string.

Here is an example of how the content looks like, it's literally a plain text log.

```
======================================================================
BEGIN_TEXT

APPLEYARD IAN 23761347 BA 2 Airport Data:
Code = JFK
Name = JFK/John F Kennedy International
City = New York
State = NY
Airport Data:
Code = LCY
Name = Lcy/London City Airport            '
City = London
State = England
sysTime:XXXXXXXXX0000 year:2012 month:7 day:16 hour:7 min:10 pm,END_TEXT

======================================================================

----(1341920977.93286)
                           2012/07/10 12:03:22.582
MAP UNAVAIL-AIRPORT CHECK IN ONLY *
>

======================================================================

----(1341920977.93286)
                           2012/07/10 12:03:23.202
I

======================================================================

----(1341920977.93286)
                           2012/07/10 12:03:23.337
IGND 
>

======================================================================

----(1341920977.93286)
                           2012/07/10 12:03:23.337
9V/BA2R16AUGJFKLCY

======================================================================
```

This was my original idea:

```
var content = document.body.textContent; //But there is no body!
var pos = content.search("UNAVAIL-AIRPORT"); // Just an example to search for
```

So my questions are:

1. How do I capture that content?
2. Once I get the position of the string, how can I scroll there and highlight the match?
   I basically want to recreate the CTRL + F function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is a webpage, how does it come there is not a body?

Comment: There is always a body in html document. The body *tag* doesn't have to exist in markup, but the body *element* does exist. If you serve this as html, it will be in `document.body.textContent` indeed.

Comment: I don't think the result (the log per se) is an HTML document. If you do a view source you see the exact same thing. It's like looking at a TXT file from a browser. The script will be injected as a bookmarklet.

Comment: @fedxc `The script will be injected as a bookmarklet.` -- Aha! That's hugely important information, and it should be edited into the question. (Without mentioning you are writing a bookmarklet, most people will assume you have another page where are pulling in the text file via Ajax or an iframe.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load a text file as a web page in your browser, your browser creates a bare-bones HTML scaffolding around the text:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <pre>[your entire text document here]</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

This doesn't show up if you view the source of the page, but it is visible if you insect the page (e.g. with Firebug or Chrome dev tools).

A simple way to manipulate and style the text is to grab the `innerHTML` of the `<pre>` block and add tags into it:

```
function highlightText(regexStr) {
    var preTag = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0];
    preTag.innerHTML = preTag.innerHTML
                         .replace(new RegExp("("+regexStr+")", "g"),
                                  "<span style='background-color:orange;'>$1</span>");
}

highlighText("some regex phrase to highlight");
```

Add whatever styles you like in the `<span>` to achieved the desired highlighting effect.

Note that the string you pass into `highlightText` is used in a regex, so you should escape special regex characters like `$` and `^` before you pass the string into the function (or make the function sanitize its own input).  This has been addressed in [How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript/494122#494122):

```
str.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = '';

    $.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
        content = data;
    });
```

2-) $(content).find() what you are searching for and add a class to highlight

Comment: `find` won't work here since it's all plain text, not an HTML document. `find` won't locate any DOM elements, because there are no DOM elements at all.

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. Everything must be done within the callback function (i.e. vars declaration also).

Comment: @sp00m Are you objecting to separation of the declaration and assignment of `content`?  There is no reason why a function cannot reference a variable that exists in an outer scope. The `content` in the callback simply refers to (and sets the value of) the `content` defined in the outer scope.

Comment: @apsillers It can, but it's too confusing. `content` won't be necessarily initialized after (DOM-speaking) the AJAX request.

Comment: @sp00m I think I misunderstood you before. Do you mean that all **manipulation** of `content` that uses the result of the Ajax call must take place inside of (or be triggered by) the callback?  Yes, of course, I agree with that. However, you might still use an outer scope in certain specialized cases (e.g., `content` is constantly set and reset by repeated Ajax calls and is read by event handlers that read its current value at the time of the event). I can appreciate this is not one of those cases, and the `content` declaration may as well be contained inside the callback.